# Spring bean's DESTROY-METHOD attribute and web-application "prototype"d bean

Tags: java, spring, scope, javabeans

Can get work the attribute "destroy-method".

First, even if I type non-existing method name into "destroy-method" attribute,

Spring initialization completes fine (already strange!).

Next, when a bean has a "prototype" scope, then I suppose it must be destroyed before the application

is closed. That not happens, it is simply never called in my case.

Though, after extracting this bean I can call this method explicitly and it does its job.

Could you explain why this method is never called in my Spring 2.5 case?

p.s. The method exists, it is public and has no arguments.

It seems to be a more difficult task then I thought.

The problem is that this destroy method is called whenever the context is closed, and
this is a rare case.

My question is this:

I have a web app. I have a "prototype"-scoped bean.

What I need is when the current session is closed, this destroy method was automatically called by Spring.

I can do it by hand, but is there any solution how to make Spring do this job? It destroys the bean after the session is destroyed, it might be possible for Spring to call a method on that bean before destroying it?

p.s. Spring does not manage the lifecycle of prototype beans, so Spring does not destroy them :)

Comment: maybe you should try to look into aspects

Comment: can you explain what this bean does, why you need to destroy it on each session, etc? I have a feeling that you might be asking a question based on what you think you need to solve but that the true problem/issue might have a far easier solution. For example, is this bean handling some sort of resources (such as a database connection)?

Comment: @matt b Suppose, when session closes this bean must log a statement "I am being destroyed." I see now that Spring DOES NOT HANDLE prototypes, so there's only one way: do it manually, in a servlet, by hand. Spring cannot really help here.

Comment: Is that the full extent of your use case? If so, just use a HttpSessionListener.

Comment: @Espen @matt b I just need a session scope ! Spring manages it, and of course I can use it instead of the "prototype". Wonderful!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Spring container doesn't manage prototype beans.

A snippet from the [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype):

> Thus, although initialization
>   lifecycle callback methods are called
>   on all objects regardless of scope, in
>   the case of **prototypes**, configured
>   destruction lifecycle callbacks are
>   not called.

If possible, try the request or session scope.

> When the HTTP Session is eventually
>   discarded, the bean that is scoped to
>   that particular HTTP Session is also
>   discarded.

Btw: The session and request scope only works if you're using a web-aware `ApplicationContext` such as `XmlWebApplicationContext`