# Managing the life cycle for non-singleton beans in Spring

Tags: spring

In "Pro Spring 2.5" it is said that

> Spring doesn’t manage the life cycles of beans that are configured as
>   nonsingletons.

So how do we manage the life cycle of non-singleton beans?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring: How to cleanly terminate prototype-scoped beans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154736/spring-how-to-cleanly-terminate-prototype-scoped-beans)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809773/spring-beans-destroy-method-attribute-and-web-application-prototyped-bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [the spring reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype), it says

> The client code must clean up prototype-scoped objects and release expensive 
>          resources that the prototype bean(s) are holding. To get the Spring container to
>          release resources held by prototype-scoped beans, try using a custom bean 
>          post-processor, which holds a reference to beans that need to be cleaned up.